# TSQL How to order parameter values with "ALL"?

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008, union

I am developing an SSRS 2008 report and am trying to get one of my stored procs to output "-All-" unioned with the other possible values for this parameter, where "-All-" appears as the first value.  Instead, "-All-" is sorted in alphabetical order so that "Adams" is listed first.  How do I make "-All-" come first?  (Note that this parameter is a uniqueidentifier, so I cannot make "-All-" = -1.  Here is my T-SQL code right now:

```
Select NULL As [client_id], NULL AS [id_no], '-All-' As [full_name], '-All-' As [id_and_name]
UNION ALL
Select Distinct [people_id] AS [client_id], [id_no], [full_name], [full_name] + ' : ' + [id_no] AS [id_and_name]
From [evolv_cs].[dbo].[service_track_current_view] With (NoLock) 
Order By [full_name]
```

When I tried this code:

```
Select NULL As [client_id], NULL AS [id_no], '-All-' As [full_name], '-All-' As [id_and_name]
UNION ALL
Select Distinct [people_id] AS [client_id], [id_no], [full_name], [full_name] + ' : ' + [id_no] AS [id_and_name]
From [evolv_cs].[dbo].[service_track_current_view] With (NoLock) 
Order By 
CASE [full_name] WHEN '-All-' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
```

[full_name]

I got this error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'full_name'.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible for you to add a column, then you could add `0 AS [sort_value]` to the first part of the union and `1 AS [sort_value]` to the second part of the union.

Then simply `Order By [sort_value],[full_name]`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
Turns out we can't use the column names that we've assigned within the query, from the `ORDER BY` clause. This updated code should work, however:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    Select NULL As [client_id], NULL AS [id_no], '-All-' As [full_name], '-All-' As [id_and_name]
    UNION ALL
    Select Distinct [people_id] AS [client_id], [id_no], [full_name], [full_name] + ' : ' + [id_no] AS [id_and_name]
    From [evolv_cs].[dbo].[service_track_current_view] With (NoLock) 
)tbl
ORDER BY
    CASE [full_name] WHEN '-All-' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    [full_name]
```

That is, you first order by whether or not the value is `-All-`, and within those two groups, you order by the actual value itself.

Comment: +1 - It's important for OP to realize `ORDER BY` applies to the whole `UNION`ed data set, not just the last `SELECT`

Comment: David, I tried ur code but got the error message displayed above.

Comment: Thanks, but I decided to just create a temp table with the [sort_value] field added, as CWilliams recommended and this fixed it!